# how do I use :var arguments in sh code for ob-shell in org-mode

Tags: org-babel

I want to pass variables/arguments to a shell script in org-mode babel code-block by using the `:var` tag.  Instead of reading the value of the variable, shell is just getting the literal `x`, which is empty (so `${x}=""`).

I would like the bash code block below in org-mode / org-babel to output "bar".  How do I do that?

```
#+name: foo :var x=bar
#+begin_src bash 
echo x
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can put in the `#+name`.

This should work:

```
#+name: foo 
#+begin_src bash :var x="bar"  
echo $x
#+end_src
```

Comment: :facepalm: of course! ><.  it's always something stupid with me :D